# Can a Thread t1 call the function "x.funcA()" when Thread t2 is currently executing the same function? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Good evening,

I have two questions to the following code..

1. Can a Thread t1 call the function f.funcA() when Thread t2 is currently executing f.funcA()?
2. Can a Thread t1 call the function f.funcB() when Thread t2 is currently executing f.funcA()?

I'd be nice if someone could explanation why yes or why not.

```
public class Foo() { 
...
synchronized void funcA() {....}
synchronized void funcB() {....}
...
}

Foo f = new Foo();
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

And as some people think this is "homework".. it is not.

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see?

Comment: Not really. That'd be too less code for homework ;).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: Nathan, thanks.. that was a mistake. synchronized is a protection of common memory. In this case it blocks the class-object ... I think.

Answer (score 0):

Each object instance has one lock. Thread `t2` will hold the lock on `f`, and it won't allow thread `t1` to acquire that lock until it exits `funcA()`.

Now, if `funcA()` and `funcB()` were `static` (class) methods, there would be a single global lock, and in that case, thread `t1` wouldn't be able to acquire that lock until thread `t2` exits `funcA()`.

Comment: Sorry.. that was a mistake. It is only f.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have a question.. Basically t1 always exits funcA() and thread t2 can execute it every time.. except t2 calls funcA() in the funcA() itself, or?

Comment: @David your question is not clear. I think you are asking whether a single thread can recursively call a synchronized method. Yes, it can. Java's intrinsic locks are *reentrant* which means if the thread holds the lock already, it can enter synchronized blocks multiple times, and then as it exits those blocks, it retains the lock until it leaves the first block it entered.

Comment: For me it's unclear how the following can happen: Foo x = new Foo(); Foo y = new Foo(); x.start(); y.start();.. how can it happen to call the function y.start() when x is executing it... y.start() is executed when x.start() has finished... the program does not jump out in middle of the function and continues executing the code that is left and the not-finished function at the same time. I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

> For me it's unclear how the following can haben:

```
Foo x = new Foo();
Foo y = new Foo();
x.start();
y.start();
```

> how can it happen to call the function y.start() when x is executing it?

`x` is not executing anything.  `x` is a reference to an *object* that has data and *methods* (e.g., x.start()).  Methods belong to objects, but they are executed by *threads*.

If some thread, t1, executes the snippet of code above, it will first create a new Foo and store a reference to it in the variable, x.  It will then create a second instance, and store a reference to that in the variable y.  It will then call x.start(), and finally, after x.start() returns, it will call y.start().

If a second thread, t2, is also executing the same snippet at the same time, then t2 will do exactly the same things that t1 does; and if the variables, x and y, are *local* variables, then the two threads will not interact with each other at all:  Each thread will have its own x and its own y.

Things get more complicated if either x or y is a shared variable (e.g., a static variable or an instance variable of an object that is known to both threads.)  When threads operate on shared variables, that's when you want to use `synchronized` to prevent them from interfering with one another.

---

**Additional Info:**

What if `class Foo extends Thread`.

That makes the `start()` calls somewhat more interesting, but it does not change anything that I said above.  The thread that executes the snippet still will call `x.start()`, and only after that returns will it call `y.start()`.

The difference is, each start() call will create a new thread, so that after the snippet finishes, there will be three threads running instead of just one.  The two new threads will not necessarily run the same code snippet as the first thread.  Each of them will start executing x.run() or y.run(), and the definition of that method controls what the new threads will do.

Comment: This made me understand it. Thank you.